# Error when installing Magento 2.1.2 on VPS

Tags: php, magento

Keep getting to this point in the install (around 58%):

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...

DDL cache cleared successfully

Installing user configuration...

Enabling caches:
Current status:
Array
(
[config] => 1
[layout] => 1
[block_html] => 1
[collections] => 1
[reflection] => 1
[db_ddl] => 1
[eav] => 1
[customer_notification] => 1
[full_page] => 1
[config_integration] => 1
[config_integration_api] => 1
[translate] => 1
[config_webservice] => 1
)


Installing data...
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Installing data... 

[ERROR] exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-samples_title' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_CODE'' in /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#5 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#6 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(514): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#7 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#8 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php(1445): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('eav_attribute', Array)
#9 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php(814): Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->_insertAttribute(Array)
#10 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Setup/InstallData.php(97): Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'samples_title', Array)
#11 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(844): Magento\Downloadable\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#12 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(796): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data')
#13 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#14 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#16 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#19 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#20 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#21 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#22 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#24 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#25 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#26 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#27 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-samples_title' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_CODE', query was: INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#4 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#5 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(514): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#6 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ea...', Array)
#7 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php(1445): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('eav_attribute', Array)
#8 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php(814): Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->_insertAttribute(Array)
#9 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/Setup/InstallData.php(97): Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'samples_title', Array)
#10 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(844): Magento\Downloadable\Setup\InstallData->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#11 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(796): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup), 'data')
#12 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#13 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(344): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#15 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#16 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#19 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#20 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#22 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#23 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#24 /home/tuneyour/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#25 /home/tuneyour/public_html/setup/index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#26 {main}
```

Tried this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/pdo-exception-error-on-index) and set `mysql.default_host` as `127.0.0.1` instead of (I guess) the default of `localhost`, but it didn't help.

No idea where to go from here, can't get past this error.